# Corona SDK: Init Table to create Playfield

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I want to create a playing field in LUA / Corona with lets say 100 x 100 fields. All of them are blanks, but for my different levels, I would like to save for each of the "non-blanks" which are the winner tiles. Those can be multiple per line or just a single one. While creating the playfield, I would like to check with level[x][y] ~= nil if this is a winner tile and needs to be created differently.

What is the best format to save the level in? I cant get this to work:

```
level = {}

table.insert( level, {{1, 4, "start"}, {1, 4, "start"}} )
table.insert( level, {2, 4, "basic"} )
table.insert( level, {3, 4, "basic"} )
table.insert( level, {4, 4, "basic"} )
```

as the for loop cant validate the x and y coordinates.

```
y = 0

while display.actualContentHeight - (y * height * 3/4) >= 0 do

    local offset = y % 2
    for x = 0, perRow-1 do

        if(level[y][x] ~= nil) then
            -- create winner

        else
            --create looser

        end

        local color = {0,1,0}
        if(x == 4) then
           color = {0,1,1}
        end


    end
    y = y + 1
end
```

Comment: "I can't get this to work" is not a proper problem description. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different approaches.  (Did you even [look at the manual?](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert))

The `table.*` functions work with what are (essentially) lists.  Indices don't matter, values are moved around by inserting/removing things.  This…

```
table.insert( level, { {1, 4, "start"}, {1, 4, "start"} } )
table.insert( level, {2, 4, "basic"} )
-- etc.
```

creates a structure like this:

```
level = {
    [1] = { {1,4,"start"}, {1,4,"start"} },
    [2] = {2,4,"basic"},
    -- etc.
}
```

You're inserting a table that contains multiple values at the end of the `level` list.  You *can* (almost) use that, using different code:

If you don't check if `level[x][y] ~= nil` but go

```
local special = false
for _, field in ipairs( level ) do
  if field[1] == x and field[2] == y then
    special = field[3] ; break
  end
end
```

`special` will be true for special fields.  (But your first entry is different and will break it unless adjusted.)

If you use this, you don't actually need to do `table.insert`, you can simply write

```
level = {
    { x = 1, y = 4, what = "start" },
    { x = 2, y = 4, what = "basic" },
    -- etc.
}
```

which is easier to read: change the `if` to

```
  if field.x == x and field.y == y then
    special = field.what ; break
  end
```

---

Problem is, you're then iterating over the whole list for every field… which isn't too bad for a few dozen entries but *will* eventually become too slow if things get bigger.

So the other approach is to create a "2D array", a table of tables of things.
The `table` library has nothing to do with that, so you manually create this:

```
-- let SIZE be whatever your level height is
level = { } ; for i = 1, SIZE do  level[i] = { }  end
```

At that point, for any integer `y` with 1 <= `y` <= `SIZE` and any `x`, `level[y][x] = nil`.  So now just go and say

```
level[1][4] = "start"
level[2][4] = "basic"
-- ...
```

and then `level[y][x]` will be non-nil for special fields.

A further tweak: If your `y` is nonsense (e.g. out of bounds, wrong type, ...) this will crash.  You can make it produce a more readable error by saying (e.g.)

```
setmetatable( level, {
  __index = function( _, k )  error( "bad access at y="..tostring( k ) )  end,
} )
```

which will get you e.g. "bad access at y=0" instead of an "attempt to index a nil value".  In the other direction, you could

```
local dummy = setmetatable( { }, { __newindex = function() end } )
local dummy_f = function()  return dummy  end
setmetatable( level, { __index = dummy_f, __newindex = function() end } )
```

and then any bad access would silently be ignored instead.  (This means other code doesn't have to treat border tiles special – there just won't ever be anything outside of the map.  So saying `level[-1][5] = "foo" ; print( level[-1][5] )` will actually leave the level unchanged and print `nil`.)